# Training the SyntaxNet POS Tagger in SytaxNet

Tags: syntaxnet

I had some difficulties training SyntaxNet POS tagger and parser training and I could find a good solution which I addressed in Answers section. if you have got stuck in one of the following problem this [documentation](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet) really helps you:

1. the training, testing, and tuning data set introduced by [Universal Dependencies](https://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/repository/xmlui/handle/11234/1-1548?show=full) were at `.conllu` format and I did not know how to change the format to `.conll` file and also after I found `conllu-formconvert.py` and `conllu_to_conllx.pl`I still didn't have a clue about how to use them. If you have some problem like this the [documentation](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet) has a python file named [`convert.py`](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/blob/master/convert.py) which is called in the main body of [`train.sh`](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/blob/master/train.sh) and `[train_p.sh][5]` to convert the downloded datasets to readble files for SyntaxNet.
2. whenever I ran bazel test, I was told to run bazel test on one of stackoverflow [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576159/training-syntaxnet-from-parser-trainer-test-sh-importerror-cannot-import-name), on [`parser_trainer_test.sh`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/parser_trainer_test.sh) it failed and then it gave me this error in `test.log`: `path to save model cannot be found :  --model_path=$TMP_DIR/brain_parser/greedy/$PARAMS/ model`

the documentation splited train POS tagger and PARSER and showed how to use different directories in `parser_trainer` and `parser_eval`. even if you don't want to use the [document](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet) it self you can update your files based on that.
3. for me training parser took one day so don't panic it takes time "if  you do not use use gpu server" said [disinex](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/175)

Answer (score 4):

I got one answer from [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/175) from [Disindex](https://github.com/dsindex) and I found it very useful. 
the documentation in https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet includes:

```
convert_corpus
train_pos_tagger
preprocess_with_tagger
```

As [Disindex](https://github.com/dsindex) said and I quote: " I thought you want to train pos-tagger. if then, run `./train.sh`"